# Update a control based on a property name to which it is not bound

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have some code that calculates several values. Once the calculation is done, I want all affected controls to update.

Easiest to explain with code...

**XAML:**

```xaml
<TextBlock x:Name="A" Text="{Binding PropertyA}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="B" Text="{Binding PropertyB}" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```cs
public decimal PropertyA { get; set; }
public decimal PropertyB { get; set; }

public void CalculateAandB()
{
    PropertyA = 12m;
    PropertyB = 14m;

    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Recalculated"));
}
```

In some way, I would like both A and B to update with their respective new value when the `"Recalculated"` event is raised.

I would like to do it in XAML, not C# code, and I don't want to replace the whole ViewModel since only a subset of the ViewModel's properties are changed.

Comment: Just raise the `PropertyChanged` event on your `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` as is customary in WPF.

Comment: @Sheridan Yes, that's the obvious answer :) I forgot to mention explicitly that I don't want to do that, or rather that I'm interested in alternatives.

Comment: You have run into this problem *because* you didn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly and you will continue to do so *whenever* you don't implement it correctly... there really is no sensible reason for any WPF developer not to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either raise `PropertyChanged` for every property, which bindings you want to update:

```
public void CalculateAandB()
{
    PropertyA = 12m;
    PropertyB = 14m;

    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyA"));
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyB"));
}
```

or group properties into separate, nested view model:

```
class SubViewModel
{
    public decimal PropertyA { get; set; }
    public decimal PropertyB { get; set; }
}

class ViewModel
{
    public SubViewModel SubViewModel { get; set; }

    public void CalculateAandB()
    {
        SubViewModel.PropertyA = 12m;
        SubViewModel.PropertyB = 14m;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SubViewModel"));
    }
}

<TextBlock x:Name="A" Text="{Binding SubViewModel.PropertyA}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="B" Text="{Binding SubViewModel.PropertyB}" />
```

Comment: The nested ViewModel is acceptable, although I was hoping for something better. But if nothing else comes along...

Comment: @TorbjörnKalin: why don't you replace auto-implemented properties with full implementations of them? This way `PropertyChanged` will be raised in property setter, and code will become cleaner.

Comment: My properties are linked and they always change together. Having only one well named argument for PropertyChanged would communicate that, and it would also result in less code.